# Use of "the" in a phrase

Tags: word-usage

I'm editing a text and came across this sentence:

**If that sounds like your cup of tea, head over there to meet *the* charming Kumamon in person today.**

I feel that "the" is used incorrectly, as Kumamon is the name of the mascot--name in the sense of "Bill" or "Robert" is a name.  I asked some other people in the office and they felt that there was nothing wrong with "the" because "the" is used in titles such as "The Amazing Randi" (a magician and skeptic.)  I argued that the writer of the article means that the bear has a charming personality and that "The Charming Kumamon" is not its title.  In other words "...head over there in person to meet Kumamon who is charming."  They replied "Right, so there's nothing wrong with using "the"  Your sentence is more awkward so it can be cleaned up by shortening to "the charming Kumamon."  I disagree. For example, "I was told to talk to the smoking man." it is unclear whether the man is smoking a cigarette or he himself is smoking (as in "on fire.") so it is unclear if the bear is charming people or if the bear is charming.  I was told I was being nitpicky and that everyone knows what the meaning is because of the context.

Is the sentence as given above OK for the meaning "Kumamon is a bear who has a charming personality," in that people like him?  I think there's something fishy about the construction.

Comment: It's perfectly fine. It's an idiomatic way to present an epithet. The meaning is "*Kumanon the charming* [one]". Epithets can evolve to become titles or proper names -- for example Alexander **the Great** -- but that obviously doesn't always happen. Generally, English puts its modifiers before its nouns, hench the word order.

Comment: @deadrat well, I understand epithet but I don't think the author intended that.  She's not available to ask.  If it were an epithet, shouldn't it be capitalized?

Comment: It's an epithet by definition. And no, epithets are not capitalized until they become part of the name.

Comment: I disagree that "the smoking man" could mean "a man on fire". Contrast it with "a smoking dish" or "a smoking gun". The definite article seems necessary to refer to a specific and "charming" Kumamon which denotes some difference from "ugly, unattractive, etc." Kumamon. If you contrast "Image of charming Mickey Mouse" and "image of the charming Mickey Mouse", I think the latter sounds more idiomatic. I guess the noun "character" is implied at the end.

Comment: @Rathony yeah, I just don't know on this one.  I would prefer to say "Kumamon who is charming."

Comment: @deadrat maybe I'm mixing up "title" with "epithet."  However, epithets are a cornerstone of the Iliad and they don't usually have the article..."swift footed Hermes" not "the swift footed Hermes."

Comment: Yeah. I am not sure, either. Let's wait for other answers. Good question.

Comment: @michael_timofeev *maybe I'm mixing up "title" with "epithet."* It's easy to check, no?

Comment: @michael_timofeev *epithets are a cornerstone of the Iliad* Are you kidding me with this? Do you think Homer wrote *The Iliad* in English? If the article is absent in an English *translation*, that's likely because the Greek doesn't have an article.  Which it doesn't for the epithets for Hermes. None of which, by the way is *swift-footed*. But you'll find "**the** swift-footed Hermes" in poems written in English. GIYF.

Comment: @michael_timofeev No one made me an overlord here, and if you'll re-read my comments, you won't find that I've issued any commands. How would that even work? Check to find out whether you're confused about the difference between *epithet* and *title*. Or remain ignorant. Max NIxt to me. But I'll tell you who I am: I'm the guy who checked *The Iliad*.

Comment: *I don't care for your snarky arrogance.* "Yeah, I've had complaints about it, but it keeps getting worse."

Comment: *I'm the guy reading the Iliad right now* In Greek? (Which is what I meant when I said I checked.) If so, good on you, but if that were the case, it seems odd to me that you draw a conclusion about English usage.

Comment: @michael_timofeev *Let's stay away from each other.* You're under the mistaken impression that we're anywhere near each other. My comments aren't about you; they're about what you post. I'd encourage you to respond to what I've written and not the tone you've imagined, but I wouldn't want you to think I'm ordering you around.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Have you reached Book II yet? Go to line 278, where you'll find ***ὃ** πτολίπορθος Ὀδυσσεὺς* with the Greek definite article. For an English translation that retains the article with ***the** sacker of cities Odysseus*, check out Robert Merrill's version.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfectly normal idiomatic use of the definite article.

By saying something like "I was introduced to none other than **the** remarkable Michelle Obama", the definite article emphasises the adjective describing them.

It can be used with any and most descriptive labels - "**the** infamous Jack the Ripper", "**the** talented Meryl Streep","**the** brilliant Stephen Hawking" etc.

Comment: I'm ok with the examples you gave, but when an "ing" participle is used, I feel something changes.  But, I'm not sure, so I'm asking.

Comment: @michael_timofeev If the *...ing* word is used as an adjective it seems to make no difference e.g. *the winning Usain Bolt**, the *blundering Joe Bloggs*.